# Multithreading - synchronised value vs mutexes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, shared-memory

When writing multithreaded code, I often need to read / write to shared memory. To prevent data races, the go - to solution would be to use something like `lock_guard`. However recently, I came across the concept of "synchronised values" which are usually implemented something in the lines of :

```
template <typename T>
class SynchronizedValue {
    T value;
    std::mutex lock;
    /* Public helper functions to read/write to a value, making sure the lock is locked when the value is written to*/
};
```

This class Synchronised value will have a method `SetValueTo` which will lock the mutex, write to the value, and unlock the mutex, making sure that you can write to a value safely without any data races.

This makes writing multithreaded code so much easier! However, are there any drawbacks / performance overhead of using these synchronised values in contrast to mutexes / lock_guard?

Comment: Can you provide the equivalent code that doesn't use a synchronized value as above? That said, if you are using lots of locks because different threads compete (!) for shared resources, you should rethink your design. Communicate and cooperate instead. This has nothing to do with your question though, but I have a feeling that you're headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This is just a general c++ question out of pure curiosity, as I try to understand multithreading... I am not even using multithreading in my project right now!! :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The code with a lock_guard would just have a global mutex and instantiate a lock_guard at the beginning of each multithreaded function.

Answer (score 2):

If you look under the hood at what is actually happening in each case you just find different ways of saying and doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

> are there any drawbacks / performance overhead of using these `SynchronisedValues`...?

Before you ask whether there is any drawback, You first ought to ask whether there is any benefit.  The standard C++ library already defines `std::atomic<T>`. You didn't say what `/* public helper functions...*/` you had in mind, but if they're just getters and setters for `value`, then what does your `SynchronizedValues<T>` class offer that you don't already get from `std::atomic<T>` ?

---

There's an important reason why "atomic" variables don't eliminate the need for mutexes, B.T.W.  Mutexes aren't just about ensuring "visibility" of memory updates: The most important way to think about mutexes is that they can protect *relationships* between data in a program.

E.g., Imagine a program that has multiple containers for some class of object, imagine that the program needs to move objects from container to container, and imagine that it is important for some thread to occasionally count *all* of the objects, and be guaranteed to get an accurate count.

The program can use a mutex to make that possible. It just has to obey two simple rules; (1) No thread may remove an object from any container unless it has the mutex locked, and (2) no thread may release the mutex until every object is in a container.  If all of the threads obey those two rules, then the thread that counts the objects can be guaranteed to find all of them if it locks the mutex before it starts counting.

The thing is, you can't guarantee that just by making all of the variables `atomic`, because `atomic` doesn't protect any relationship *between* the variable in question and any *other* variable.  At most, it only protects relationships between the value of the variable before and after some "atomic" operation such as an atomic increment.

When there's more than one variable participating in the relationship, then you must have a mutex (or something equivalent to a mutex.)

Comment: NOTE:
- std::atomic require trivially copyable classes
- also in some cases it is implemented only for specific set of primitive types (stm32 for example only offer atomic up to 32bit primitive) so you have to use mutex

Comment: @Lesto, Yes, but when I wrote that answer I should have put the second part first. It's more important. The ability to implicitly synchronize individual variables, either with `Atomic<T>` or with the OPs `SynchronizedValue<T>`, has far fewer use-cases than the ability to explicitly synchronize a _group_ of variables using a separate mutex. OP asked "are there any drawbacks [to] using these synchronised values in contrast to mutexes...?" My answer should have been that `SynchronizedValue<T>` works as well as a mutex is the cases where it works at all, but `mutex` works in far more cases.